# Особенности работы с Vue.js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

При назначении элемента часто происходят непредвиденные ситуации.
Например если в контейнере с `id='app'` разместить `canvas`, то при назначении переменной с таким `id`, содержимое холста не показывается.
Другой пример. Теперь в контейнере находятся любые элементы. И мы изменяем их стиль. Примерно так:

```
elem = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
elem[0].style.background = 'yellow';
```

Однако, при использовании vue.js переназначение стиля по факту не происходит. Если в консоли задать значение `elem[0].style.background` выдаваться будет `'yellow'`. Но в html и сss кодах ничего не меняется.
Почему это происходит?

Comment: Приведите полный код пожалуйста

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Например если в контейнере с id='app' разместить canvas, то при назначении переменной с таким id, содержимое холста не показывается.

Когда в dom'е оказываются несколько элементов с одинаковым id, getElementById возвращает первый из них. А поскольку canvas вложен в другой элемент, тот элемент будет идти раньше канваса и именно с ним вместо канваса ты попытаешься что-то сделать.

> Если в консоли задать значение elem[0].style.background выдаваться будет 'yellow'. Но в html и сss кодах ничего не меняется.

Вероятно, у тебя в переменной ссылка на элемент, который уже не находится в dom'е. Vue по какой-либо причине пересоздал его и поместил в dom новый элемент, а ты продолжаешь работать со старым.

Впрочем, именно с `getElementsByTagName` такое невозможно в связи с живостью этой коллекции. Скорее всего в реальном коде ты сохраняешь в переменную не коллекцию, а сам элемент, либо используешь `querySelecorAll`.